# About the representation ring of a compact group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, kt.k-theory-and-homology

A question stuck in my mind when I was reading the paper "The representation ring of a compact Lie group" by Segal. He says on page one that I confine myself to the case of a compact Lie group G: in general $R\left( G\right) =\underrightarrow{\lim }R\left( G/N\right) $, where $N$
runs through the compact normal subgroups of $G$ such that $G/N$ is a
compact Lie group.

Here $R\left( G\right)$ is a representation ring or character ring of $G$.

My question is that what is the relation between representation rings of compact totally disconnected group and finite group. Compact totally disconnected groups are inverse limit of finite group. Moreover, what can we say about the induced map $R(G/N)\rightarrow R(G)$, where $N$ is a compact totally disconnected normal subgroup of $G$. Can this map be a monomorphism or isomorphism?

Comment: It's pretty easy to see that for a profinite group completed Burnside ring agrees with projective limit of Burnside rings of quotients by open normal subgroups. Not so sure about representation rings.

Comment: Every continuous representation of a profinite group over C factors thorough an open normal subgroup so the representation ring is the direct limit of the representation rings of the finite images.  This is because any closed subgroup of GL_n is a lie group, any continuous image of a profinite group is profinite and any compact totally disconnected lie group is finite since the component of the identity has finite index

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I do not understand the relevance of your answer to my question

Comment: You asked about relationship with representation ring of finite groups.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Segal says this. The short exact sequence $0\rightarrow N \rightarrow G \rightarrow G/N \rightarrow 0$ induces $0\rightarrow R(G/N) \rightarrow R(G) \rightarrow R(N) \rightarrow 0$, where $G/N$ is a Lie group. This sequence is exact? And what is the $R(N)$? What Segal says that $R(G)$  is determined with $R(G/N)$. How is determined the direct limit?

Comment: Given an rep of G you can restrict it to N and the restriction is trivial iff the rep is inflated from G/N.  The only detail to check is R(G) to R(N) is onto.  This doesn't seem clear to me since if an irrep of N appears in a rep of G, then so do all its conjugates under the action of G.

Comment: The sequence you wrote is not exact for finite groups. For example if G is the group of all invertible maps of the form ax+b over the p-element field, then the translations x+b form a normal subgroup N but the restriction map R(G) to R(N) has image generated by the trivial representation and the sum of all non-trivial representations.  This seems to me a proper subring of R(N).  I would guess the image of R(G) would be the ring of G-fixed points for the action of G on R(N) induced by conjugation.